# Can we import or inlcude a Json file in another Json file in javascript or angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In my project I have two Json files.

1) File1.json

```
{
  "abc" : 123
}
```

2) File2.json

import File1.json

```
{
  "xyz": 567
}
```

I need a way in javascript or angular js, which would help me achieve a file

File3.json whose content will be something like this

```
{
  "abc" : 123
},
{
  "xyz": 567
}
```

Comment: "File3.json whose content will be something like this" — That's invalid JSON.

Comment: it can be something like this right ?

[ { "abc" : 123}, { "xyz" : 567} ]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Node and FileSystem

You will need to change you files contents to:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
           "abc": 123
        }
    ]
}
```

And

```
{
   "array": [
      {
          "xyz": 567
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
const fs = require('fs'); // Require Filesystem
let files = ['/File1.json', '/File2.json']; // The files you want to merge
let newData = { 'array': [] }; // The new data object. 

files.map( ( file ) => { // Loop the files
    fs.readFile( file, function read(err, data) { // Read file and pass data and the response
        if (err) { // Handle error
            throw err;
        }

        let parsedJson = JSON.parse(data) // Turn data into JSON

        parsedJson.array.map( ( object ) => { // Loop the array of objects.
            newData.array.push(object); // Push the object into the new structure.         
        });
    });
})

fs.writeFileSync('/File3.json', newData); // Write the new file.
```

I didn't actually run this but this should work.

Also i would suggest you use a Database instead of handling data in JSON files. Checkout Mongo DB it does this all for you :)

Comment: You could also completely remove the .array and make the object [{ "abc": 123}]

Comment: Thanks Nicolay ! But I have to go for this approach because in internationalization I am dynamically loading moduleName-eN.json. However there is one common-[languageCode].json which needs to be loaded along with the moduleName-[languageCode].json .

Comment: Ahh can you not just combine the contents of the files and save it as a const?

Comment: Hey @Nicolay ! I just found out a way to achieve what I wanted. And Achieved it through promise chaining. :)